# How can I get Opera to accurately populate the Speed Dial portion of the taskbar context menu?

Tags: taskbar, context-menu, opera

The taskbar recent documents lists are a very handy feature in Windows 7+.  Opera 18.0 uses a variation on this, showing pages from your Speed Dial instead.  Groovy!  Except the documents shown are not remotely like those I use most often.  Is this feature not yet fully implemented, or is my installation broken?  If the latter, how can I fix this?

Here's my current context menu:

[image: Opera Speed Dial on the taskbar context menu]

...and indeed these five sites are on my Speed Dial.  However, I have many more, sites I use much more often.  It looks like this list is simply not being updated, as I believe these sites are some of the first I set when I set up Opera on this machine.

I can pin or remove an entry from the list by right-clicking it, but I don't see how to add an item.

Comment: I think you're confusing Opera's speed dial (which is driven by where you place items on your speed dial) with Chrome's thumbnails (which are driven by how frequently you visit sites). My speed dial shortcuts in the menu reflect the exact order I have on my speed dial tab.

Comment: Nope; as illustrated in the pic, I'm talking about Opera.  The shortcuts shown do correspond to the sequence that pages appear on the Speed Dial page at the moment, though this is not always the case: I added a new page to the start of my Speed Dial months ago, but it just recently appeared on this list.

Comment: I realise you're talking about Opera - but it seems to me you're still missing the point about the speed dial, not some "recent items" or "most used items" list, being in the menu. I've just added a new item to my speed dial and moved it to the front of the list, moved two others around, and checked the context menu - it was updated to reflect the speed dial entries as I'd expected. Not all programs making use of this context menu populate it with "most recent" entries; Comodo Dragon, for instance, shows "most visited" and "recently closed" entries. Opera shows the speed dial.